# Having Issues using Array Of Records

Tags: vb.net

My project is to have an array of records predefined and then have them output into a list box at high school using the following syntax [syntaxt here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfD8M.png) however it outputs the error "System.Exception: 'Late-bound assignment to a field of value type 'Contact' is not valid when 'Contact' is the result of a late-bound expression.'"

I've tried lots of troubleshooting and can't find the issue - it's probably something really simple. I'd appriciate any help you guys can offer.

Public Class Form1

```
'Dim addressbook(8, 2) As String
'Dim number As i

Structure Contact

    Dim Forename As String
    Dim Surname As String
    Dim address As String

End Structure

Dim addressbook(8) As Contact

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    setuprecords(addressbook)
    displayoutput(addressbook)

End Sub
Sub setuprecords(ByRef addressbook)

    'For row = 0 To 8
    ' For column = 0 To 2
    ' If column = 0 Then
    ' addressbook(row, column) = InputBox("What is your name ")
    ' ElseIf column = 1 Then
    ' addressbook(row, column) = InputBox("What is your 2nd name")
    ' ElseIf column = 2 Then
    ' addressbook(row, column) = InputBox("What is your address")
    ' End If
    ' Next
    'Next


    addressbook(0).Forename = "Bart"
    addressbook(0).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(0).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(1).Forename = "Lisa"
    addressbook(1).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(1).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(2).Forename = "Homer"
    addressbook(2).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(2).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(3).Forename = "Marge"
    addressbook(3).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(3).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(4).Forename = "Santa's Little Helper"
    addressbook(4).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(4).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(5).Forename = "Magie"
    addressbook(5).Surname = "Simpson"
    addressbook(5).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(6).Forename = "Milhouse"
    addressbook(6).Surname = "Something"
    addressbook(6).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(7).Forename = "Ned"
    addressbook(7).Surname = "Flanders"
    addressbook(7).address = "Springfeild"

    addressbook(8).Forename = "Willie"
    addressbook(8).Surname = "Something"
    addressbook(8).address = "Springfeild"

End Sub
Sub displayoutput(ByVal addressbook)
    'If number = 0 Then
    ' For row = 0 To 8
    ' ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(row, 0) & vbTab & (addressbook(row, 1) & vbTab & (addressbook(row, 2))))
    ' Next
    'Else
    ' ' ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(number - 1 & vbTab & column))
    ' ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(number - 1, 0) & vbTab & (addressbook(number - 1, 1) & vbTab & (addressbook(number - 1, 2))))
    'End If
    For row = 0 To 8
        ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(row).Forename)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(row).Surname)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(addressbook(row).address)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change setuprecords to

```
Sub setuprecords(ByRef addressbook As Contact())
```

While it was just `ByRef addressbook`, it was defaulting to type `Object`.

Put `Option Strict On` as the first line in your code and it will notify you when you forget to specify a necessary type.

You will see that

```
Sub displayoutput(ByVal addressbook)
```

also needs the same attention.

Comment: Thank you djv! 

This solved my issue right away. My teacher never taught us about this